# Saving image to file with IImageEncoder

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, image-processing

do you have a working code to share.

I’m trying to figure out how to save to a file an IBitmapImage image.

I need to resize existing .jpg file and it seems like the only API for Windows Mobile. I managed to load it convert it to IImage -> IBitmapImage -> IBasicBitmapOps and resize it finally, but I have no clue how to save it properly to a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IBitmapImage::LockBits` to get access to the image data via its `BitmapData*   lockedBitmapData` parameter. Use the `BitmapData` to prepare a bitmap file info header, then write that one and the image data in `BitmapData::Scan0` to a file using regular file writing with `::WriteFile` or higher level ones if you use such.

Comment: This example seems to do what you want: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid743B2B2FCDBFE91584C329A50766C1155709DA1B.aspx